# Java Spring Boot mapping for static data not valid

Tags: java

So I am just goofing around with webpages and found this cool collection of free designs here

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/812f3647744576c2f381ff30b216518c.png]

https://github.com/puikinsh/CoolAdmin

I added all of the static resources (css/fonts/imgs/js/vendor) to my own personal project to try to rip some stuff to mess around with forms and what not!

I made a simple Index page in attempt to completely copy the index page just to make sure everything was working, and I got an unexpected result.

I have Spring Boot/Default settings should make my static via /resources/**

```
2018-12-28 05:59:07.422  WARN 16540 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]         
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET 
/static/vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js
2018-12-28 05:59:07.422  WARN 16540 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET 
/static/vendor/wow/wow.min.js
2018-12-28 05:59:07.422  WARN 16540 --- [io-8080-exec-10] 
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET 
/static/vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js
2018-12-28 05:59:07.423  WARN 16540 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] 
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET 
/static/vendor/counter-up/jquery.counterup.min.js
2018-12-28 05:59:07.423  WARN 16540 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] 
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET 
/static/vendor/counter-up/jquery.waypoints.min.js
```

I get this for all of the static/** files that are embedded in my HTML like so:

```
<link href="../static/css/font-face.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

The only java files I have thus far is the TestController and the SpringBootApp.

```
@RequestMapping({"", "index"})
public String getIndex() {
    return "index3";
}
```

The web page shows the HTML but no CSS/JS/ect.

[image]

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Where have you stored the files in your projects precisely (post the exact and complete path of font-face.css), and what is the URL of the page you're looking at in your browser (post the complete URL of the location bar of your browser).

Comment: <link href="/css/font-face.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

Gives me - 

No mapping for GET /css/font-face.css

is the result I get, same with the rest for their respected directory

Comment: You're not answering my questions.

Comment: You adjusted your comment - I updated my OP with my information 

The url I am going to is localhost:8080

Comment: So you're at the root. There is nothing above the root. So the path `../static` doesn't make sense. What is under static is served at the root by Spring boot. So having `static` in the path doesn't make sense either. All you need is `href="css/font-face.css"` (relative URL) or `href="/css/font-face.css"` (absolute URL). If that doesn't work, it means that you're not using a standard spring boot configuration.